Google Ads cannot load because of timeout (Ad failed to load : 3)
I implemented a banner ad but it does not load any ads.
Here are the specified permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AD_ID" />

Here is the Ads meta-block in AndroidManifest.xml. I am currently using the sample application ID:
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

In my code, I use the ad unit ID for testing ((/6499/example/adaptive-banner). Here is the Java code snippet from the main activity, it is called from onResume():
private void loadBanner () {
    adView = new AdManagerAdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId ( useTestAds ?
            BannerAdUnitIDTEST : BannerAdUnitIDPROD );
    adView.setAdSize ( getAdSize() );

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams (
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT );
    lp.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    lp.startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    lp.endToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    adView.setLayoutParams ( lp );
    adContainerView.addView(adView);

    loadAd();
}

private void loadAd () {
    AdManagerAdRequest adRequest = new AdManagerAdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

And this is an Logcat extract:
Ads                      I  SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v240304000.240304000.0
                         I  HTTP timeout: 60000 milliseconds.
                         I  Ad failed to load : 3
...
Ads                      I  This request is sent from a test device.
DynamiteModule           E  Invalid GmsCore APK, remote loading disabled.

To my knowledge, error code 3 means ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL ("The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory."). The second Logcat line indicates a timeout, and the last line could be linked to the problem, but I'm not sure.
So what could be the reason that there is no ad loaded? Does the HTTP timeout mean that my internet connection does not work (but at the same time, the app is able to connect to a database server!)?
